# Wrapping hierarchical data around li tags with doctrine2-nestedset

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, hierarchical-data

I am using https://github.com/blt04/doctrine2-nestedset to manage my hierarchical data.

It manages hierarchy with following database structure:

```
 categories
 -id
 -root
 -lft
 -rgt
 -name
```

I need to wrap a node with li tags as below:

```
 Vehicles
    Bikes
       Pulsor
       Hero Honda
    Automobiles
    Trucks
```

This bundle provides with following methods for manipulating a node:

```
$tree=fetchTreeAsArray($nodeId);  //fetches tree for that node
$node->getNumberDescendants();    //returns all descendants for that node
```

More description of methods at https://github.com/cbsi/doctrine2-nestedset/blob/master/README.markdown

I want to wrap the node around li tags:

I tried so far this:

```
         $tree = $nsm->fetchTreeAsArray(8);
    $treeLiTags="<ul>";
    foreach ($tree as $node) {
        $treeLiTags.="<li>".$node;
        if ($node->hasChildren()) {
            echo $node->getNumberDescendants();
            $treeLiTags.="<ul>";
            $closeParent=true;
        }
        else {
            if ($closeParent && !$node->hasNextSibling()) {
                $closeParent=false;
                $treeLiTags.="</ul>";
            }
            $treeLiTags.="</li>";
        }
    }
    $treeLiTags.="</ul>";
    echo $treeLiTags;
```

This returns as below:

```
Vehicles
    Bikes
       Pulsor
       Hero Honda
          250 cc
       Automobiles
       Trucks
```

I should be getting:

```
Vehicles
   Bikes
      Pulsor
      Hero Honda
         250 cc
   Automobiles
   Trucks
```

Any algorithm would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [Doctrine Extensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions)  implementation of [nested set (tree)](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md)?

It already has implemented what you are trying to achieve - you can simply use:

```
$repo = $em->getRepository('Entity\Category');
$options = array(
    'decorate' => true,
    'rootOpen' => '<ul>',
    'rootClose' => '</ul>',
    'childOpen' => '<li>',
    'childClose' => '</li>',
    'nodeDecorator' => function($node) {
        return '<a href="/page/'.$node['slug'].'">'.$node[$field].'</a>';
    }
);
$htmlTree = $repo->childrenHierarchy(
    null, /* starting from root nodes */
    false, /* load all children, not only direct */
    $options
);
```

Comment: thanks for the link to nested set tree read me file. I guess I will try this extension